# How to delete border in ViewCell From Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I can not remove the border in the ListView. Here is a photo. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQe8M.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView provides the `SeparatorVisibility` property to get or set a value that tells whether separators are visible between items.

Set the `SeparatorVisibility` property to `None` would remove the separator lines in Listview.

```
  <ListView SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>mono</x:String>
                <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
    </ListView>
```